# enum class - printf prints wrong value

Tags: c++, c++11, printf, integer-promotion

I have this `enum class`:

```
enum class myEnum : u8{
    LEVEL_ERROR = 0,
    LEVEL_WARN = 50,
    LEVEL_DEBUG = 150,
  };
```

and at some point I making use of it (not exactly this way, but simply this is what happens):

```
myEnum instance = 42;
printf("My enum is now: %u", instance);
```

**EDIT**: Of course it is used this way: `myEnum instance = (myEnum)42;`

And printed value is sometimes `298` sometimes `126657066` but never `42`. So what I noticed is that all of this "random" numbers are my value but padded with 3 bytes of whatever (stack ?) - `42 = 0x2A`, `298 = 0x12A` and `126657066 = 0x78CA22A`. I understand that my type is getting promoted to int but it should be padded with 3 bytes of "0" in case of unsigned variable type. So why is is padded with garbage ?

Comment: `%u` seems wrong when your `enum class`s underlying type is a unsigned 8 bit integer. How about you remove the `: u8` and let the underlying type be the default `int`? Or change `%u` to match the type you are *actually* printing?

Comment: I tried `%d` and `%c` - no result. I want to use u8 I must be sure that I know my enum length and I want it to be the shortest possible - 1 byte.

Comment: How about `printf("My enum is now: %u", static_cast<int>(instance));` then?

Comment: Also, you cannot assign directly a `42` into the `myEnum`. You need to use `static_cast` or direct-list-initialization in C++17.

Comment: Just as a side note: Since this is C++, you probably should better be using something other than `printf`… ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type is not getting promoted to `int`. Integer promotions are applied to variable argument list arguments of enumeration type *if* they are subject to integer promotions [[expr.call]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#12). The problem is that integer promotions only apply to unscoped enumerations [[conv.prom]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom). Your `enum class` is a scoped enumeration. Therefore, the value will not be promoted and your call to `printf` has undefined behavior due to mismatch between the argument type and the type specified in the format string (as also explained in the comments above). You will have to either explicitly cast the value to the integer type you want or change your `enum class` to an unscoped enumeration…